# Eclipse SVN shows incoming change when no changes

Tags: eclipse, svn, subclipse

After committing all changes to my SVN repository, I always see "incoming change" on my folders.

[image]

I have found similar posts here on StackOverflow, but none ended with a solution.  Someone did mention that their repository was set up incorrectly, but did not elaborate.

Any ideas where I can begin investigating?

I am using Juno Service Release 1 Build id: 20120920-0800 and SVN version 1.6 with the following plug-ins:

[image: sand]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must have the Subclipse feature to Show Out of Date folders turned on (it is not on by default).  This blog post describes the feature:

http://markphip.blogspot.com/2006/12/subclipse-synchronize-feature-show-out.html

I generally do not recommend using it, which is why the preference is off by default.